# SKSpriteNode not working with Random Number Array

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, arc4random

I have a SKSpriteNode that is spawn repeatedly. I have created a random number generator and have tried to associate the returns with a different Sprite Image. However, it does not work. The numbers are being generated randomly but even if "2" is returned the SKSpriteNode is drawn as "Fire Barrel 1".

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var firstObstacle = SKSpriteNode()
var player = SKSpriteNode()
var randomValue = Int()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    createPlayer()

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
    let repeatingAction = SKAction.run(repeatingSequence)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([ delay, repeatingAction ] )
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))

}

func randomSelector() {
    let array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    let randomValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    print(array[randomValue])
}

func createPlayer() {
    player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
    player.setScale(0.4)
    player.position = CGPoint(x: -player.size.width, y: 0)
    player.zPosition = 1
    addChild(player)
}

func createObstacle() {

    if randomValue == 2 {

        firstObstacle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fire Barrel 2")

    }

    else {

        firstObstacle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fire Barrel 1")

    }

    firstObstacle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: -self.frame.height / 2 + firstObstacle.size.height / 2)
    firstObstacle.zPosition = 1
    addChild(firstObstacle)
}

func repeatingSequence() {
    randomSelector()
    createObstacle()

    let moveObstacle = SKAction.moveBy(x: -self.frame.width - firstObstacle.size.width, y: 0, duration: 5)
    firstObstacle.run(moveObstacle)
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is

```
let randomValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
```

You are doing what is called "variable shadowing". randomValue also exists at the class instance level, but here because you use `let` you've declared a local scoped version.

The actual value of `self.value` is `Int()` which is 0. Hence why it is "First Barrel l".

The generalized design you're using is not really good. Unless you have some real reason where you need to hold `randomValue`, you should not make it a class instance variable. Instead pass it by argument.

This would look something like:

```
func randomSelector() -> Int {
    let array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    return  Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
}

func createObstacle(type:Int) {
    if (type == 2) {
        // Type 2 stuff
    } else {
        // Other stuff
    }

    // Rest of your stuff
}

createObstacle(type: randomSelector())
```

Although given the nature of how this works, you don't even need the argument, you could just do:

```
func createObstacle() {
    if (randomSelector() == 2) {
        // Type 2 stuff
    } else {
        // Other stuff
    }

    // Rest of your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Very clear instruction and explanation, much appreciated.